# How do I create role for read only permission of product in magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, user-roles

I want to create an admin user whose access is only to read the products in Magento 2. I checked but was only able to give the user access together with Edit and Delete action which I don't want to give

The access that I want to give to the admin user

- **Product View**

The access that I don't want to give to the admin user

- **Product Edit**
- **Product Delete**

Seeking help to provide solution or the nearest possible solution that can help achieve solution on this matters

Thank you

Comment: you can do this using ACL 

Check here https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/permissions-user-roles.html

Comment: @WaqarAli unfortunately it still makes the user able to edit and delete the product even though I only tick at Catalog > Inventory > Products > Read Product Price permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option in Magento 2, you may create a system configuration where you can select admin users to prevent edit and delete the Product.
And you can add your custom JS code on catalog/product/index and catalog/product/edit
Page to remove Add New Product, Maas Action drop-down and from the edit page you can remove Add Attribute and Save Button.

Or you can create a plugin before save and delete, and add your logic there.

Comment: Thank you for the information and suggestion